# htaccess redirect page but do not show file

Tags: .htaccess

I have a page which I'm redirecting using PHP:

```
header('Location:notices.php');
exit;
```

Is it possible to hide the page name entirely using .htacess? So instead of the browser showing the URL `http://example.com/notices.php`, it instead shows `http://example.com` but in effect it really loaded`http://example.com/notices.php`.

I'm open to any other solution since my goal here is just to *not* show the actual page being loaded.

**EDIT:** The browser still loads notices.php (not /index.php) but the URL shows /. Only the URL changes, or in this case, masks the file being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

notices.php:

```
<?php
   include('index.php');
   exit();
```

doing a header() redirect WILL show the new url in the browser. That's unavoidable. You've told the browser "go over there", so it obediently does.

The other option is to use mod_rewrite to silently rewrite requests for /notices.php into a request for /index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your .htaccess file in the root folder of example.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)?\.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteRule . notices.php [L]
```

All requests to example.com will show notices.php, if this is what you really want.